# Remove Adjustment Rows SQL Select Statment

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I would like to remove adjustment rows from my SQL select query. Here is what I have right now:

```
Resource    Date    Leave       Position    Hours   Code
33333   26/02/2016  Sick Leave  TRNSPLNR    -7      SICK                     
33333   26/02/2016  Sick Leave  TRNSPLNR     7      SICK                     
33333   26/02/2016  Vacation    TRNSPLNR     7      VAC
```

This is what the end result should be:

```
Resource Date       Leave     Position   Hours  Code                   
33333    26/02/2016 Vacation  TRNSPLNR    7     VAC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that there are exactly 2 such duplicates, you can do:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.date = t.date and 
                        t2.leave = t.leave and
                        t2.resource = t.resource and
                        t2.hours = - t.hours
                 );
```

It is not clear what makes a duplicate, so you might want to add more comparisons into the inner `where` clause.